# How do you normalize an FFT in python?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to plot frequency vs power in python of a complex valued data array. However, I can't seem to quite get the values correct. I believe there is a normalization error somewhere. Using numpy, what I have is

```
datafft = np.fft.fft(dataArray)                 #FFT of the data array (units of volts)
datafft = datafft/np.sqrt(len(datafft))/2/np.pi #Sad attempt at normalization and not correct
datafft = np.fft.fftshift(datafft)              #Shifts the zero-frequency component to the center of the spectrum.

N = len(datafft)                                #Number of data points#

V2 = [datafft[i].real**2+datafft[i].imag**2 for i in range(N)]  #Getting units of volts^2
powdbm  = [10*np.log10(V2[i]*20) for i in range(N)]             #The 20 comes in from a 50Ohm resistor and units of mW overall (1000/50)
```

Does anyone know what the normalization should be?

Comment: Have you taken a look at their [documented normalizations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#implementation-details)?

Comment: @mgilson I've tried to use that but doesn't give the correct values.